# Create table and populate from csv/xls

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, xls

I am trying to create and populate a table from a csv or xls file by sql code directly. The problem is that I have no clue on how to start, and only relevant info i found is [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/tutorial.asp?tutorial=203) but the solution is using a wizard, not sql code.

Anyone can give me some tips or ideas from where to start please?

Answer (score 0):

```
BULK INSERT table
FROM 'c:\csvtest.txt'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

from http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/